# checkbox in custom ListView and selectAll button bug

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I am facing a problem now that I really don't know what is going on.

First let me explain what I want to do.
I am having a custom ListView that show my user detail and a checkbox beside it. At first, if I checked all the checkbox, the selectAll checkbox will not check on by itself.

Therefore, I have implemented the codes below. It works perfectly at first, but in the end I found out that if I have too much item that require me to scroll down, the system like detected that I have uncheck the checkbox and help me to deduct my "count".

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if(buttonView == selectAll){
        selectAll.setChecked(isChecked);
        for(int i = 0; i < theList.size(); i++){
            theList.get(i).setSelected(isChecked);
            theList.get(i).setCheckAll(isChecked);
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }else{
        int position2 = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();
        if(isChecked){
            theList.get(position2).setSelected(true);
            System.out.println("count here positions:"+ position2);
            count++;
            System.out.println("count here:"+ count);
            if(count == theList.size())
            {
                selectAll.setChecked(true);
            }
            //String this_is_the_comment = theList.get(position2).getApprComments();
            //System.out.println(this_is_the_comment);
        }else{
            theList.get(position2).setSelected(false);
            count--; //when i scroll down the if condition will come to here
            System.out.println("count here: -- "+count);
            if (selectAll.isChecked()) {
                selectAll.setChecked(false);
                for (int i = 0; i < theList.size(); i++) {
                    theList.get(i).setSelected(true);
                    theList.get(position2).setSelected(false);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Please kindly help me with this bug. I am lost and stuck for 3 days.

Comment: guys. sorry for my bad english, the problem I am facing now is that, when I scroll down the screen,  I will get into count--; which is I don't know why will this happened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `onCheckedChanged` method at last you need to check if all the items are checked if yes then  perform `selectAll.setChecked(true);`

add this at last in your method

```
boolean allChecked=true;
for(int i = 0; i < theList.size(); i++){
    if(theList.get(i).isSelected){
        checker=false;
    }
}
if(allChecked){
    selectAll.setChecked(true);
}
```

Comment: ya, i did its here selectAll.setChecked(true);

Comment: no in your code its not there...  it must be at last without any condition

Comment: the problem I am facing is that, I keep go into my else condition if i scroll down the screen. When it go to my else condition mean that my count will be --

Comment: in your if condition match **buttonView.getId()==selectAll.getId**

Comment: I want my selectAll checkbox to check if I have selected my all my items one by one. Because now if i check my selectAll checkbox all my items will be selected but now I need it to be the other way around which the selectAll checkbox will be checked if all of my items are selected

Comment: yes @HoeLuen thats i am trying to say.  if isChecked boolean is true then perform a for loop to check if all other checkboxes are checked. If yes, then set selectAll.setChecked(true);. This must be at last in your method

Comment: may i know how do i check if my checkboxes are checked? because i only can use getTag other than getCheckedItemPositions() as i am using list

Comment: paste this code at last in your method.<br/>

**boolean allChecked=true;
  for(int i = 0; i < theList.size(); i++){
            if(theList.get(i).isSelected){
    checker=false;
   }
        }
  if(allChecked){
   selectAll.setChecked(true);
  }**

Comment: oh my god. @Rahul Khurana although i didnt follow exactly what you have told me but your for loop and your theList.get(i).isSelected really helped me a lot. i have solved my problem. thank you very much. do you want to edit your answer so i could choose it as best answer? TQ TQ TQ TQ i am really appreciate ur help

Comment: @HoeLuen glad it helps .Please accept it as answer and upvote. Thanks